# Executing java main class on a remote server using Ant

Tags: java, ant

I need to copy some .class files to a remote server and execute the main class file using ANT script.
I 'm able to copy the files using the SCP ant target ,but i'm stuck on which task to execute for running the main class on a remote server.The main class also accepts couple of arguments for execution as well.Can anyone provide any pointers on how to achieve the same.

Comment: Hi ,I used the above task ,but I'm getting following error while executing :[sshexec] Exception in thread "main" 
  [sshexec] java.lang.ClassFormatError: com.CheckinScheduler (unrecognized class file version)
  [sshexec]    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
  [sshexec]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
  [sshexec]    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
  [sshexec]    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
  [sshexec]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)

Comment: The JVM installed on the remote machine is a different version.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [SSHEXEC](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html)?

```
<sshexec host="somehost"
username="dude"
password="yo"
command="java YourClass args"/>
```

JRE installation is required on the remote server.

Comment: Hi ,I used the above task ,but I'm getting following error while executing :

Comment: Please make sure the java version is same on local machine and remote server. You can check java version in following command: `java -version`

Comment: Yes,The versions were different on both machines.Now , can anyone help me set JAVA_HOME using the ANT script using the sshexec task.

Comment: maybe you can try `command="export JAVA_HOME=<path/to/your/jdk>;java YourClass args"`.